# Put images in grid with css

Tags: css, grid

can't figure out how to achieve that result (separate logos like in image). Maybe someone can help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a quick demo for you. [**CHECK THIS JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/Jp6TM/1/)

Here I used background images for creating borders. Just Tweak it!!!

Cheers.

Comment: Wow, superb solution! But only with css3 compatible browsers. Maybe there is another way?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox (3.6+), Safari/Chrome (1.0/1.3+), Opera (10.5+) and even Internet Explorer (9.0+) all support the multiple background feature. enough???

Comment: You are right :) IE sucks, just wanted to be sure about other ways. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
    <div class="logo-box" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:980px;
    float:left;
}
.logo-box {
    width:245px;
    float:left;
    height:150px;
}
```

You can put whatever HTML `img` tags or CSS `background` within the `.logo-box` elements

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
   float:left;
}
```

this will work (you should define the height and the width of the img's too)

Comment: thanx, i know, but the most important thing is lines and spacing between images exactly like in picture.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a nice solution: http://unmatchedstyle.com/news/building-a-client-logo-grid-with-centered-elements.php
- all images centered horizontally and vertically
- easy to make responsive
- easy to customize specific image sizes
- seems to be very cross-browser compatible, even with old crappy IEs

HTML:

```
<article class="clients">
    <span></span><img src="images/img-logo2.png" alt="logo" />
</article>

<article class="clients">
    <span></span><img src="images/img-logo3.png" alt="logo" />
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article.clients {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 203px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #4d4d4d;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       -moz-border-radius: 3px;
                 border-radius: 3px;
}

article.clients * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

article.clients span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
```